# How to revert back to OpenJDK?

Tags: java, openjdk

I had installed sun-java, but I want to revert back to OpenJDK 7. I was trying to re-install from the terminal using the command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`, same from Synaptic and Software Center, but it does not work.

I try to use the command `java -version` and then I get a message like `The java program can be found on follow packages» open-7-jre-headless`

So, I tried to install it, but they ARE installed on my system...

I do no want format my PC just for Java.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Can you add the output of `apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 update-java-alternatives
```

to switch between different implementations without removing or reinstalling and downloading packages.

Answer (score 2):

In order to switch between installed Java versions, you can use the `update alternatives` command.

- To obtain a list of the installed Java packages on a system, run the following command from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>):

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```

  This will give a list output similar to the following:

  ```
  There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
     Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1070      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1069      manual mode
  Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
  ```

In this particular case, the Oracle Java 7 version is the current default(indicated by the asterisk).

In order to switch to the OpenJDK version, you would select option `1` at the prompt and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You will now be running the OpenJDK 7 version.

No other changes will be needed to switch your Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate Sun Java altogether...

You can use `dpkg-query -l *sun-java*` to see the sun-java related packages that are installed. You can use `sudo apt-get purge sun-java`, etc., with the names of the package(s) to get rid of them.

If OpenJDK is already installed, that's great. Hopefully it'll just work from there. If not, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` might get you figured out.

If it still doesn't work, try repeating the package removal/purging process above for OpenJDK and re-installing it to start from scratch.