# How do I remove SUN Java and use OpenJDK instead?

Tags: 11.10, java, openjdk, jdk, jre

As a programmer I use java for learning to code in Netbeans. I installed Sun java 6 long time ago over openJDK that came with my ubuntu just cause it seemed more responsive...

Now that oracle left the repos I wanted something easy to handle to install and uninstall, so I want to Remove completely sun java 6 from my computer and set as default OPENjdk....and openjre.

I already have installed OpenJDK and OPENjre...but not marked as default.

Besides I want to clean Sun java from here, dont wanna get messy ^^.

Running ubuntu 11.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert back to OpenJDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94433/how-to-revert-back-to-openjdk)

Answer (score 1):

In terminal try the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-jre:amd64 sun-java6-jre:i386
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: gives me a `virtual packages like sun-java6-jre cannot be removed`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the package names are (investigate using Synaptic), but something along the lines of:

```
apt-get purge sun-java6-jre
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

should do the trick. `apt` should take care of all the configurating and resetting the default `java` to `openjdk`.

Comment: getting this on both commands:sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-jre
                                                          Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'sun-java6-jre' can't be removed                                                                     
...tried already that earlier but no luck :/...

Comment: `sun-java6-jre depends: sun-java6-bin, suggests: sun-java6-fonts, sun-java6-plugin`. Have you tried removing those separately?

Comment: No luck gettint this on "bin" and "plugin": "Unable to locate package" and in "fonts": unable to remove package. What I really dont get is this. When I go to check Java version says I got Java 6 23 and offers me to upgrade to version 6 30. But I have OPENJDK 7 and OPENJDK 6 installed...if I remove those I ahve to say goodbay to Jdownloader, so Im guessing I have OpenJDK installed but SUNJAVA is default on my system..(At least in firefox or network applets)... really dont know what to do wanna delete SUNJAVA!!!! damn XD

Comment: Just to check, what do you get when you run `java -version`? 

I get `    lws@helios:~$ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_30"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)`